# Input type hidden value not being recognized when deployed on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, supabase

Whenever, I try to update the data on Vercel, this is the error that it shows:

```
invalid input syntax for type uuid: "undefined" - unable to save
```

However, it successfully updates the data when done locally.

This is how I submit the form:

```
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="p-8 text-gray-600 w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
          <input type="hidden" value={water_types.id} name="id"/>
         //inputs

          //button
        </form>
```

Submit function:

```
  async function onSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault();
        try { 
            const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
            const res = await editFunction(formData);

            
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err, "error");
            if (err instanceof Error) {
                setMessage(err.message);
            } else {
                setMessage("An error occurred");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the server action:

```
export async function editFunction(formData: FormData): Promise<{ message: string }> {    
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    const supabase = createServerActionClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })
    const {data: {user}} = await supabase.auth.getUser();

    try{    
      const name = formData.get('name')
      const price = formData.get('price')
      const idValue = formData.get('id');

      console.log(formData, "formData") //data shows correctly on the console
  
        const {data, error} = await supabase.from('db')
            .update({
                name, price
            }).eq('id', idValue)

          console.log(data, "data")
          console.log(error, "error")
        
        if(error){
            return {message: `${error.message}  - unable to save`}
        } 
        return { message: `Succesfully added the data` }
    }catch(e){
        return {message: "Failed to submit the form."}
    }

}
```

It seems that when deployed on Vercel it does not recognize the `input type hidden`, however, I am also using this in another module and the update just works fine.

[image]

```
create table
  public.db (
    id uuid not null default uuid_generate_v4 (),
    name text not null,
    price numeric(10, 2) not null,
    user_id uuid not null,
    constraint db_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint db_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references profiles (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

Comment: please check you are getting value in your input field {water_types.id} in this water_type object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that you wanted to assign a value to UUID, but, instead of passing a valid value, you pass `"undefined"`, which cannot be converted into UUID. Since `value` is `water_types.id` and it turns out to be `"undefined"`, you end up having this error.

You mentioned that this does not happen for you at localhost, but it happens on Vercel. This strongly implies that there is a difference between your local setup and Vercel setup. Look at configurations and unversioned files in order to spot the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server actions, should you not be using the 'action' attribute on the  element, instead of the 'onSubmit' attribute?

Regarding the uuid, I would recommend a guard clause that checks the id type,  for example:

```
  if (!formData.get('id')) {
    throw new Error('id is required')
  }
```

Or better still, a tool like zod to check the formData matches the correct schema before sending to the database.